# Using regex to parse through loop to display only matching results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, twitter, gsub

**Issue:** I am having issues resulting results from a loop that match a specific regex.

I am dabbling with the Twitter API to result usernames (username2) who tweeted at another user (username) and i created this in my **controller:**

```
@user_results = TwitterApi.client.search("to:username1", result_type: "recent").take(10).collect do |tweet|
     puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}" if tweet.user.screen_name.gsub(/\A^username2\z.*/)
```

Then loop like this in my **view:**

```
<% @user_results.each do |user| %>
  <%= user %>
  <% end %>
```

This results nothing even when there *should* be results.

**If i use** `"#{tweet.user.screen_name}".gsub(/\A^username2\z.*/)`

**It results:**

`<Enumerator:0x00007fb3a4b2f2a0>`

**I also triedd:**

`tweet.user.screen_name.gsub(/\A^username2\z.*/) { |match| "#{tweet.user.screen_name}"}`

But it results all results instead of the one to match

This works fine if i lose the `puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}" if tweet.user.screen_name.gsub(/\A^username2\z.*/)` and just use `"#{tweet.user.screen_name}"`.  With that, all usernames appear.

The regex i use if correct and works with all variations within Regx101 website.

**I want** to only have results come up or be true if a specific username appears.

What am i doing wrong? Is it the controller snippet or the view side?

Overall, I want to be able to result the username, and give a true || false.

Comment: Did you mean something like `puts tweet.user.screen_name if tweet.user.screen_name =~ /\Ausername2\z/`?

Comment: Same results.  Nothing appears.  I think the .gsub is on the right direction with the enumerator error.  I'm definitely doing something wrong tho with it

Comment: `gsub` method is a substrings replacement method, not a matching method. That "if" will always be true since the result of gsub is always a string, it's not in the right direction. Use the regexp matching operator `=~` like @WiktorStribiżew said.

Comment: At any rate, the regex is not good: `^` must be removed and `.*` must also be removed, they  both should be removed.

Comment: @arieljuod okay ill continue trying new ways using the =~ ... i did try a handful after Wiktos comment but none seems to work so far

Comment: Even when using `puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}" =~ /\w+/` --- still nothing appears. or soemthing like `puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}" if tweet.user.screen_name =~ /\w+/`

Comment: now im on the right track.  its the regex itself.  I got `tweet.user.screen_name if tweet.user.screen_name =~ /[1-2]/` to only appear names with numbers.... just need to get the regex to work with mine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   tweet.user.screen_name if tweet.user.screen_name.match('username2')
```

this matches any regex or string within the `()`

My final is this:

```
TwitterApi.client.search("to:username", result_type: "recent").take(10).collect do |tweet|
       tweet.user.screen_name if tweet.user.screen_name.match(/#{@record.username}/i)
end
```

This way the results are true no matter of case insensitivity

Comment: This code has worked (i did end up using a slightly different version to this) but not sure why this is downvoted.  I tested it and tried to beat it and couldn't so its just about full proof.  If theres a reason you think its bad code, please give your corrections or ideas on it